# sql server compatibility full text stoplists and noise words

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, resources, compatibility-level, noise-words

if I am running sql server 2008 in compatibility level 90 (sql 2005) does it use the stoplist in the resource database or does it use ftdata\ENU.txt files???

also if I make my own stoplist in 2008 (using compatibility 100) can I ignore the system stoplist and use my own with my full text queries or will it use the system and my custom stoplist??

I have loads of fulltext indexing questions.  any good sql resourses on web dealiing with stoplists, mutliple contains across multiple tables.  large record sets????

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ok.  for associating a full text search with a stop list it is in the create/alter

ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table_name
   { ENABLE 
...
   | SET STOPLIST { OFF| SYSTEM | stoplist_name }
     [WITH NO POPULATION] 
   }
[;]

what about if I am in compatibility mode 90 (sql 2005)??  will I have to use the text files???